# How to read correct port from tracker response using peers (binary model)

Tags: java, networking, byte, bittorrent

Im trying to read the response of the binary model of the trackers' response of the peers, I manage to read the IP, but the port is where the problem is.

There are other posts about this problem but none of them are in java where an unsigned short does not exist. As such the ports I read from the data are either very large or negative.

I have already tried using a char instead of a short, but this did also not work.

An example of how im reading it at the moment is this:

```
ByteBuffer wrap = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
wrap.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
return wrap.getInt();
```

Where bytes is a byte[] array of size 2, which came directly from the tracker.

Comment: Your *motivation* for the question might have something to do with bittorrent, but the actual question is just how to do some bitjuggling from one type to another and is independent of the source of those bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get two bytes as a number from a ByteBuffer is the `getShort` method. To reinterpret its signedness you then use [Short.toUnsignedInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Short.html#toUnsignedInt(short)).